# Bootstrap4Xpages 2.3.2 with jQuery 2.1.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I have some html pages that we are putting into an XPage application that use bootstrap 2.3.2 and jQuery 2.1.1.  I have july 2014 version Bootstrap4Xpages plugin installed, and was using the theme 'bootstrapv2.3.1r'.  However, it automatically loads jQuery 1.11.  Is there a way to turn off the call  to jQuery 1.11 in the plugin and call jQuery 2.1.1 ?  If not, looks like we need to create a custom 2.3.2 theme.

Comment: I am curious, what happens when you load jquery2 as a resource on that page?

Comment: I was getting errors on the page, and the resources were not rendering correctly, but I'm not sure that it was that both versions of jQuery were loading, I am still finishing the html to XPage conversion.  XPages loads additional resources, and not in same order as my original page, so am working at creating custom controls that emulate the original html.  Also, I read up as much as I could and it appears that 1.11 and 2.1 are similar and I should be able to use 1.11 instead of 2.1.  I'm going to use this afternoon working on jQuery 1.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not like the solution...

The best course of action is to install the [Extension Library v10](http://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library/releases/C0DC8EBF7727100786257D8C00393407) which was released 2014-11-10.

This release includes Bootstrap4XPages with all updated libraries. The only catch (AFAIK): you need to switch to bootstrap v3. The differences are [outlined in the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/) and shouldn't be too hard to handle

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Because of the amount of customised bootstrap written for the pages it looks like we need bootstrap 2.  We'll eveutually upgrade to v10 of extlib, but still run July 2014 version of bootstrap plugin (for now).

My understanding of jquery is that there is little difference between the 2.1 and 1.11, other than support for older browsers.    They both share the same api, so functionally they are doing the same thing.  I have done some preliminary testing and it looks promising that we can just use jQuery 1.11, though I'm not certain yet.

Comment: Eventually you might need to bite the bullet and upgrade to v3 anyway. Bite it while it is fresh